# Declarative Spring exponential backoff

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I was looking at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/intermediate/retry-and-more/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/stateful-retry-advice-context.xml) spring-integration example and I would like to use declartive exponential backoff (int:exponential-back-off) but I can't find a proper definition of the valid arguments. I can see from the example that I can set "initial" and "multiplier" but what about "maxElapsedInterval" or something similar?

And also is there a reason why eclipse's autocompletion is not suggesting int:exponential-back-off or any of its arguments (the projects builds and runs OK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `ExponentialBackOffPolicy` (at least I don't understand it), but there is no such option like `maxElapsedInterval`. However I guess that you mean `maxInterval`.

Actually the `<exponential-back-off>` has all those attributes:

```
<int:handler-retry-advice id="a6" max-attempts="8">
    <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="3.0" maximum="10000" />
</int:handler-retry-advice>
```

Is that appropriate for you?

As for Eclipse: it is typical issue of the IDE. You just need to turn on `Spring Nature` for the project and allows it to determine XSD from Spring jars in the classpath of your project.